# Not getting the entirety of the content when using HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

In my Windows Phone 8 app I have the following code:

```
private static async Task<string> GetJson(string url, string param)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url + param);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        string responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBodyAsText;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }

}
```

This method works great except for one thing; all of the content isn't being caught by the Content.ReadStringAsync()-method.

This is the format of which the API replies to requests:

```
JSON
 -embedded
   -messages[]
 -links
```

When doing a request with a client like Fiddler, I'm getting the entirety of the response. However my windows phone app only gets the message-array, and not the links-object. This causes my serializer to fail, because I'm missing parts of the JSON object.

Does anyone understand why this is happening? I could provide additional code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to **response.Content.ReadAsAsync()** directly instead of retrieving the response as a string and then parsing it to the object.